# Threads are facing deadlock in socket program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am developing one program in which a user can download a number of files. Now first I am sending the list of files to the user. So from the list user selects one file at a time and provides path where to store that file. In turn it also gives the server the path of file where does it exist.

I am following this approach because I want to give stream like experience without file size limitation.

Here is my code..

1) This is server which gets started each time I start my application

```
public class FileServer extends Thread {

    private ServerSocket socket = null;

    public FileServer() {
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(Utils.tcp_port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            System.out.println("request received");
            new FileThread(socket.accept()).start();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

2) This thread runs for each client separately and sends the requested file to the user 8kb data at a time.

```
public class FileThread extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private String filePath;



    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public FileThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("server thread" + this.socket.isConnected());
        //this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try

        {
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            try {
                           //************NOTE
                filePath=(String) ois.readObject();             
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            File f = new File(this.filePath);

            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            int c = 0;

            while ((c = bis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                oos.write(buf, 0, c);
                oos.flush();
                // buf=new byte[8192];
            }

            oos.close();
            //socket.shutdownOutput();
            // client.shutdownOutput();
            System.out.println("stop");
            // client.shutdownOutput();
            ois.close();
//          Thread.sleep(500);

            is.close();
            bis.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

NOTE: here filePath represents the path of the file where it exists on the server. The client who is connecting to the server provides this path. I am managing this through sockets and I am successfully receiving this path.

3) FileReceiverThread is responsible for receiving the data from the server and constructing file from this buffer data.

```
public class FileReceiveThread extends Thread {

    private String fileStorePath;
    private String sourceFile;
    private Socket socket = null;

    public FileReceiveThread(String ip, int port, String fileStorePath,
            String sourceFile) {
        this.fileStorePath = fileStorePath;
        this.sourceFile = sourceFile;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            System.out.println("receive file thread " + socket.isConnected());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(sourceFile);
            oos.flush();
            // oos.close();
            File f = new File(fileStorePath);

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int c = 0;

            //************ NOTE

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());

            while ((c = ois.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                // ois.read(buf);
                bos.write(buf, 0, c);
                bos.flush();
                // buf = new byte[8192];
            }

            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            //
            os.close();
            bos.close();

             socket.close();
            //Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE : Now the problem that I am facing is at the first time when the file is requested the outcome of the program is same as my expectation. I am able to transmit any size of file at first time. Now when the second file is requested (e.g. I have sent file a,b,c,d to the user and user has received file a successfully and now he is requesting file b) the program faces deadlock at this situation. It is waiting for socket's input stream. I put breakpoint and tried to debug it but it is not going in FileThread's run method second time. I could not find out the mistake here. Basically I am making a LAN Messenger which works on LAN. I am using SWT as UI framework.

Comment: [socket.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close() "API javadoc") in FileReceiveThread.run feels slippery

Comment: @gnat : i am not getting what you are saying...Can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: BTW: You should create and flush your ObjectOutputStream before creating your ObjectInputStream or this can cause a deadlock.

Comment: And you should only use ObjectInput/OutputStream for sending objects, not raw data.

Comment: The BufferdInput/OuputStream is redundant because you are reading blocks of 8 KB (which is the default buffer size anyway)

Comment: You shouldn't just print an exception and continue as if it didn't happen.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : There is no exception generated. It just goes in waiting mode..

Comment: @PeterLawrey : as per your suggestion i removed all the redundant code. removed all the ObjectInput/OutputStream. But still the problem remains....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more basic problem.

You are only processing the first socket.

```
while(true) {
    new FileThread(socket.accept()).start();
}
```

Comment: Well, here for each file requested separate thread will be running so what i thought is there will be separate socket for each client sharing the same server. Are you trying to say that once the server's input/output stream has been used they will not be available for any other client ? Please give any good link of tutorial if you know about this issue..

Comment: As you can see, I missed the first time as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion of Peter Lawrey i removed all the redundant streams code from my source code. Now the changed source code is as follows and the problem remains.

1) No change in FileServer. It is as it is .

2)  FileThread

```
public class FileThread extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private String filePath;

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public FileThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("server thread" + this.socket.isConnected());
        // this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try

        {
            OutputStream oos = socket.getOutputStream();
            oos.flush();

            InputStream ois = socket.getInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            ois.read(buf);
            filePath = new String(buf);
            System.out.println(filePath);

            File f = new File(this.filePath);

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

            int c = 0;

            while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                oos.write(buf, 0, c);
                oos.flush();
            }

            oos.close();
            System.out.println("stop");
            ois.close();

            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

3) FileReceiverThread

```
public class FileReceiveThread extends Thread {

    private String fileStorePath;
    private String sourceFile;
    private Socket socket = null;

    public FileReceiveThread(String ip, int port, String fileStorePath,
            String sourceFile) {
        this.fileStorePath = fileStorePath;
        this.sourceFile = sourceFile;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            System.out.println("receive file thread " + socket.isConnected());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            OutputStream oos = socket.getOutputStream();

            oos.write(sourceFile.getBytes());
            oos.flush();

            File f = new File(fileStorePath);

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int c = 0;

            // ************ NOTE

            InputStream ois = socket.getInputStream();

            while ((c = ois.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {

                os.write(buf, 0, c);
                os.flush();

            }

            ois.close();
            oos.close();

            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

is there still something which i am missing ?